# Generate assets in android project with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I need to pack some text files in a zip file, and put it in the `assets` folder of my Android project.
I am using gradle and android studio.
This is what I have in my `build.gradle` at the moment:

```
task textsToZip(type: Zip, description: 'create a zip files with all txts') {
    destinationDir file("$buildDir/txts")
    baseName 'txts'
    extension 'zip'
    from fileTree(dir: 'text-files', include: '**/*.txt')
    into 'assets'
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.mergeAssets.dependsOn(textsToZip)
}
```

This doesn't seem to work, I don't get the txts.zip in the right place.
I am quite new to gradle, can someone give me a hint about what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: What does not work exactly?

Comment: At the end of the build, there is no zip file in the `assets` directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, at the end I figured it out.
I created a task for every variant, this way:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def zipTask = project.tasks.create "textsToZip${variant.name.capitalize()}", Zip
    zipTask.destinationDir = file(variant.processResources.assetsDir)
    zipTask.baseName = "txts"
    zipTask.extension = "zip"
    zipTask.from fileTree(dir: 'text-files', include: '**/*.txt')
    variant.processResources.dependsOn(zipTask)
}
```

I don't know if it's the best way to go, but it worked for me, and I find it also quite elegant.

Comment: What is Zip in this context? I need this kind of task but then for compiling sass to Css for each variant. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/33285167/2072569 (you can get 50 reputation)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with latest Android Studio. Gradle Sync fails with: > Could not get unknown property 'processResources' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl.